# habtm relationship - cakephp "complex" query

Tags: cakephp, entity-relationship

i'm building a tag cloud for my cakephp website and i'm not able to build a "cakephp query":

models :

```
Tag hambt Post
Post hambt Tag
```

db :

```
tags(id, name)
posts_tags(#post_id, #tag_id)
posts(id, title, ....)
```

The sql query :

```
SELECT tags.name, COUNT(*)+10 AS fontsize
FROM tags, posts_tags
WHERE tags.id = posts_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY posts_tags.tag_id
ORDER BY tags.name ASC
```

the result :

```
objective-c 11
PHP         12
test        11
test2       11
test3       12
tutoriel    13
```

the problem :

I'd like to build the query this way (i know i could use $this->query, but this is not a complex query, there must be a way) but it doesn't work :

```
$opt = array(
    'fields' => array('Tag.name','COUNT(*)+10 AS fontsize'),
    'group' => array('PostsTag.tag_id'),
    'order' => ....
);

$tags = $this->Post->Tag->find('all', $opt);
```

EDIT : Here the answer (thanks dave)

```
$options['fields'] = array('Tag.name', 'COUNT(*) occurence');
$options['joins'] = array(    
    array(
        'table' => 'posts_tags',
        'alias' => 'PostsTag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Tag.id = PostsTag.tag_id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'posts',
        'alias' => 'Post',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
             'PostsTag.post_id = Post.id'
        )
    )
);
$options['group'] = array('Tag.name');
$options['order'] = array('Tag.name ASC');
$options['limit'] = 20;

$this->Tag->recursive = -1;

$data = $this->Tag->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: can we see your whole $opt query and the error/results you get when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a JOIN:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables

HABTM queries in Cake are not the simplest of things - but setting recursive to -1 and doing a JOIN has been the best/simplest solution I've found.

Basically, once you get used to `containable` and `joins`, you can `set recursive to -1 in your AppModel`, and just pick either containable or join depending on what data you want and how you want to query it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to repeat the code here, so just take a look at this plugin. It's exactly doing what you try to approach. https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/tree/2.0 To be more specific look at this method: https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/blob/2.0/Model/tagged.php#L52 Either copy the code (and give credit in the docblock) or simply use the plugin.